# know about the iPhone device whether it is old or new through code

Tags: objective-c

I have one problem,i want to know the code through which i can know about the iPhone device, whether the device is old or new (as Hardware point of view).
Please some one help me.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: could you be more specific? You want to know the iOS version or the device type (iPhone 3G, 3GS, iPod Touch 2G,...)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you might want to have a look at the [UIDevice class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html). It has a property `model` which returns a string like "iPhone" or "iPod Touch". You didn't say why you want to know whether a device is new or "old", but if it's about whether multitasking is supported, that's what the `multitaskingSupported` property of UIDevice is about.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the device hardware name with numbers that go higher with newer hardware:

```
char machine[256];
size_t size = 255;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
if (size > 255) { size = 255; }
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
```